Mouse clicks in VS Code have an unexpected effect in the lower part of the screen
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on amd64 PC. For certain applications, e.g. VS Code and Qt based camera viewer, clicking outside a large rectangular area in the upper left corner of the screen causes a switch to another open application or has no effect if there is no other application open. Firefox and text editor work normally. What could be the reason?

Reducing the window size from full screen to less than half screen makes the mouse/cursor behave correctly. When in full screen mode, the icons in the top right corner (minimize/maximize/close) don't work. I have to use Move in order to reduce window size.

The problem went away. Perhaps related to changing the display orientation from portrait to landscape and back.
